# StreamCorruptedException when converting byte array from ResultSet to Object

Tags: java, serialization, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I'm trying to read a byte array that I got from a MySQL ResultSet and convert it to an Object using ObjectInputStream. 
During the readObject(), the following exception is thrown:
`Java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 20`

The error doesn't always occur, but when it does, it will stay until I delete and redo this entry in the database. It's also always the same object.
Can this be because of some error when writing the Object as Blob? Or is something wrong with the data itself?

This is the code I'm using:

```
byte[] bytes = resultSet.getBytes(index);
if (bytes != null && bytes.length > 0) {
  InputStream byteInput = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
  ObjectInputStream objectInput = new ObjectInputStream(byteInput);
  Object resultObject = objectInput.readObject();
  objectInput.close();
  return resultObject;
}
```

---

**Edit**:
The error seems to be in the writing of the object, as *laune* suggested. But I still don't get how an ObjectOutputStream could write corrupt data.
I know that the close() is missing, but if I'm correct the flush() should to the same thing. At least that shouldn't lead to a corrupt byte array.
Also, there are no other threads that could change the object while it's written, and the output streams are only created for this one operation and never reused.

The code for the serialization (value is an org.w3c.dom.Document):

```
  try {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream objectStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteStream);
    objectStream.writeObject(value);
    objectStream.flush();
    statement.setBytes(index, byteStream.toByteArray());
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new PropertyAccessException("Cannot serialize object", e);
  }
```

Comment: It stands to reason that the problem is on the write side. - If something goes bad when writing, there will be something wrong with the data.

Comment: You will increase chances of getting good answer if you will provide code which will always reproduce your problem. For now we can only guess that could go wrong. Consider adding code responsible for putting your data into database.

Comment: 0x20 is an ASCII space. It seems that the bytes you're deserializing weren't the result of serialization.

Comment: I added some information about the serialization of the object. Sadly, the error is not easly reproducable, or fixing it would be much easier.